# JDBC read-only connection pools on Glassfish

Tags: mysql, glassfish

Is it possible to create a read-only connection pool in Glassfish, talking to MySql, so that no updates are allowed?  I want to have people use a replicated MySql database and I want to make sure no one tries to do updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just give select only  privileges to the user your app server connects as, so mysql will enforce that you can only select from the database, not update or delete anything.

You'd want to run something like this sql statement for that user,

```
grant select on thedb.* to 'myuser'@'host' identified by'thepassword';
```